# How can I make a << boundary >> stereotype in Visual Paradigm?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

How can I make a `<<boundary>>` stereotype in the UML software "Visual Paradigm"? I have tried, on the right side (image) but failed. It has different shape which is not suitable on the left side `<<boundary>>`.

The picture I see:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what is the expected result. Could you draw it by hand and add a picture? Do you want to have a boundary with the vertical line on the other side?

Comment: @Ister Yes, I will draw a class diagram with a vertical line, how? What should you choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the class and select **Presentation Options** to turn off the **Display as Robustness Analysis Icon** and have the boundary class show as class + stereotype form.

[image]